# Intersecting many Points with many Polygons

Tags: c#, sql-server, bigdata, intersection, sqlgeography

I have two tables in SQLServer 2014, one with ~100M points and one with ~2000 polygons.
Each point intersects with only one of the polygons. The task is to assign the ID of the intersecting polygon to the point.

What is the best practice to do it?

I have tried it in C#, loading two datatables, going row by row through the points and row by row through the polygons to find matches.

```
Boolean inside = (Boolean)polygon.STIntersects(point);
```

This is painfully slow since i have to access each point separately and each polygon multiple times to check for intersection. Any ideas are very welcome!

Create table statement for Points

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManyPoints](
     [idNearByTimeLine] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [msgID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
     [userID] [bigint] NULL,
     [createdAT] [datetime2](0) NULL,
     [WGSLatitudeX] [numeric](9, 6) NULL,
     [WGSLongitudeY] [numeric](9, 6) NULL,
     [location] [geography] NULL
)
```

and Polygons

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManyPolygons](
     [OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [Shape] [geography] NULL,
     [ID_0] [int] NULL,
     [ISO] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
     [NAME_0] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
     [ID_1] [int] NULL,
     [NAME_1] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
     [ID_2] [int] NULL,
     [NAME_2] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
     [ID_3] [int] NULL,
     [NAME_3] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
     [NL_NAME_3] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
     [VARNAME_3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
     [TYPE_3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [ENGTYPE_3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     [ORIG_FID] [int] NULL,
)
```

Both tables have a spatial index on "location" and "Shape"

Comment: What are the data types of your points/polygons ?

Comment: Datatype for both is SQLGeography

Answer (score 1):

```
Select idnearbytimeline, objectid
From dbo.manypoints as point
Join dbo.manypolygons as polygon
   On point.location.STIntersects(polygon.shape) =1
```

Comment: I did some testing with this and the expected query time will be 3.5 days. Is there a way to make it faster? Thanks for the solution anyway!

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on each of the spatial columns? If not, as them.

Comment: Also, how did you come up with that time estimate? AFAIK, there's nothing in SQL server that will give you the estimated time of completion for a query.

Comment: I have used your suggestion and added top X  for different values which seemed more or less linear. From that i guesstimated the total runtime. Probably not the right way to do. I also added the index hint since it was not mentioned in my execution plan. 
Thanks for your answer - i helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store your points of single polygon with comma separated string. So it can be covered in only one record for each polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution. This is a stored procedure which selects all points within a given polygon ID. Then I use a simple C# program to loop through all polygons. However this is still not optimal and painfully slow. Any tweaks that can be made easily?

```
USE [<<DATABASE>>]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] @ID INT 
AS 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [weiboDEV].[dbo].[<<NEW TABLE>>] ON;
-- Select Points in Polygon (Geography)

DECLARE @Shape GEOGRAPHY = (select [Shape] from <<POLYGONS>> where OBJECTID=@ID);
DECLARE @SQLString2 NVARCHAR(500)= N'INSERT INTO <<NEW TABLE>>(<<YOUR COLUMNS>>) SELECT <<YOUR COLUMNS>> FROM <<POINTS>> WHERE ([location]).STWithin(@Shape) = 1;';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@ID INT, @Shape geography';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString2, @ParmDefinition, @ID, @Shape;

GO
```